# Django | Correct way to pass key identfiers to query string

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, syntax

I was reading this Django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

It explains how to use params for preventing SQL-Injections and the documenation also just deals with paramaters, which in valid sql can become single quoted.

Django simple escapes with single quotes by using:

```
self.baz = "test"
cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
```

becomes:

```
b"UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = 'test'"
```

This shows that we cannot use the param argument for key identifiers like tablenames:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM %s", [column, table])
```

since single quotes are invalid sql query (back-ticks would be valid):

```
b"SELECT 'id' FROM 'atablename'"
```

This means that we can just pass data with string formatting e.g.:

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT {} FROM {}".format(column, table))
cursor.execute("SELECT "+column+" FROM "+ table)
```

This way we have to take care ourselfs for sql-injections.

Is there anything I am missing?

How can I escape key identifiers in Django, so that there are no sql-injection possibilites?

Comment: Would column and table namesbe provided by the end users as input?

Comment: @Shadow Yes. This is possible.

Comment: Then you really should reconsider your design!

Comment: @Shadow Can you elaborate further? What do I need to change? Is it impossible to clean `column` and `table` before handle them over to the methods? Any article you can refer me? I really want to know how to continue from here. What do I have to think about. I much aprecciate an answer.

Comment: Unless you are developing the equivalent of phpmyadmin in django, there probably is a way to avoid users directly inputing table and column names.